# ReactJS - multiline textarea

Tags: javascript, html, jinja2, reactjs

I'm trying to create multi-line text input field with ReactJS. I've created this component:

```
var TextInput = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {currentValue: this.props.children}
  },

  handleChange: function(event){
  //handler
  },

  render: function(){
    return (
        <textarea name="body"
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  value={this.state.currentValue}/>
    )
  }
});
```

I'm rendering it this way:

```
# jinja2 template
React.render(
  <TextInput>{{ post.body }}</TextInput>,                  
  document.getElementById('post-editing')
);
```

The problem: If `{{ post.body }}` is something like `#Title \n text`, the textarea show it in one line. I am seeing `#Title text` in my textarea without line breaks. What is the right way to set `<textarea>` value with ReactJS?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are setting the value of the `<textarea>` the correct way, via the `value` attribute, the issue is that the string you are getting as the value of `this.props.children` is actually not what you think it is.

With an input value of `"#Title \n text"` in your `<TextInput>` component, the value of `this.props.children` is actually `"#Title \\n text"` (notice the double backslash), you need to do something like the following to correctly output the newline character:

```
    render: function(){
      var value = this.state.currentValue.replace('\\n', '\n');
      return (
        <textarea name="body"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={value}/>
      )
    }
```

Comment: nice, but `this.state.currentValue.split('\\n').join('\n');` seems to be more appropriate. Also, it must have reversal replace `\n` => `\\n` on server

Answer (score 3):

If you specify your input value via `value` attribute then it textarea will be rendered with that value on every rerender. Instead, you should use `defaultValue`, if I understood correctly.

```
    var TextInput = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function(){
            return {currentValue: this.props.children}
        },
        handleChange: function(event){
          //handler
        },
        render: function(){
            return (
                <textarea name="body"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    defaultValue={this.state.currentValue} />
            )
        }
    });
```

Also I should mention that in React, using `props` in `getInitialState` is antipattern, but this is other question .. and [explained in official documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html).