# React textarea save to database via API PUT removing linebreaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, reactjs

I am using `$ajax` to PUT comments into a db in my react application. The comments are saved from a textarea without problem and rendered in my application - but without linebreaks.

According to this thread https://github.com/ssorallen/turbo-react/issues/22 react removes newlines intentionally. Is there a way around this in the frontend?

I've attempted several different methods (most of them a version of this one [ReactJS - multiline textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864197/multiline-textarea-in-reactjs)): Replacing `\n` with `\\\n`; replacing `\n` with `br` (not only doesn't work, but is also ugly as the html br-elements are rendered in the textarea); using `encodeURI` on PUT and `decodeURI` on `GET`. These attempted solutions have caused my API PUT requests to bug out, as it can't save the special characters from the encoded URI, and the backslashes from the `\\\n` are treated like forward slashes, and thus results in the API call getting a false search path (like `api/comment/12312/Thisisa/nComment`).

The component is pretty huge, but this is the textarea render part:

```
var resourceInputValue = this.state.resourceValue;
var commentInputValue = this.state.commentValue;
```

(...)

```
<div className="detailsForms">
        <form>
          <textarea type="text" name="comment" className="commentForm" placeholder="Comment" defaultValue={commentInputValue} onChange={this.changeComment}/><img src="img/cancel.png" className="clearComment" onClick={this.clearComment}/>
        </form>
        <div className="formButtonDiv">
          <button className="formButton" type="button" onClick={this.putComment}>Add Comment</button>
        </div>

      </div>
```

And the methods:

```
getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      commentValue: this.props.orderProps.comment
    }
  },

changeComment: function(event){
    this.setState({
      commentValue: event.target.value
    });

    if(event.target.value === "") {
      this.setState({
        commentValue: null
      });
    }
  },

  putComment: function(){

    $.ajax({
      type: "PUT",
      url: apiUrl + 'api/OrderComment/' + this.state.detailsId + "/" + this.state.commmentValue,
      beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + token);
      },
      success: function () {
        document.getElementsByClassName("formButton")[1].className += " formButtonSuccess";
        document.getElementsByClassName("formButton")[1].innerHTML = "Done!";
        clearInterval(timer);
        ajaxCallOrders();
      },
      done: function(){

      }
    }).fail(function (_d) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("formButton")[1].className += " formButtonFail";
      document.getElementsByClassName("formButton")[1].innerHTML = "Try again";
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run [encodeURI()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp) before sending the text and decode it on the back end.